# laravel mail queue give unexpected ErrorException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

i am trying to make the laravel queue work in my laravel application.

in my controller i use:
`use App\Mail\Request;`

`Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Request($result));`

to send a mail (this worked fine!)

Then now converted it to:
`Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new Request($result));` as laravel docs mentioned. But when i try to queue:work my queue, then it get failed.

Stacktrace:

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: App\Mail\Request::$content in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/app/Mail/Request.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/app/Mail/Request.php(39): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/Applications/M...', 39, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\Mail\Request->build()
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php(117): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/SendQueuedMailable.php(52): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->send(Object(Illuminate\Mail\Mailer))
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable->handle(Object(Illuminate\Mail\Mailer))
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyLaravelApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
```

Who can help me with this issue?

Comment: Could you add your code for `app/Mail/Request.php` please? It looks like the error is happening in that file.

Comment: Also what is the type of `$results`? If it is an Eloquent model instance, make sure to use the `Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels` trait in the `Request` class.